# jQueryでクリックして追加された要素にテキストをセットしたい

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).on('click', function() {
  $('body').append('<div class="t"></div>');
});
// あとから文字列をセットしたい
$('.t').html('set');
```

このままだとsetというテキストはセットされません。どうすれば、あとから文字列をセットすることができるでしょうか？

Comment: 「文字列をセット」したいタイミングはいつ・どんな風にですか？ 少なくともクリック（して要素が追加）された後に実行する必要があります。

Comment: 「あとから」って、具体的にどういう意味ですか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', function() {
  $('body').append('<div class="t">set</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.t').append('<p class="p"></p>');
    $('.p').text('set');
});
</script>

<body>
    <div class='t'></div>
</body>
```

pタグにtextを付けるのはどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

> どうすれば、あとから文字列をセットすることができるでしょうか？

「後でイベントハンドラ関数の処理を追加したい」の意でしょうか。

```js
function handleClick (event) {
  var div = $('<div class="t"></div>');
  $('body').append(div);

  var endfn = event.data.endfn;

  if (typeof endfn === 'function') {
    event.data.div = div;
    endfn(event);
  }
}

var data = {};
$(document).on('click', data, handleClick);

// 後で click ハンドラ関数の処理を追加する
data.endfn = function (event) {
  event.data.div.text('set');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```